# Asymptotic of a sum: $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{f(k)} = \int_{n}^{\infty}{f(t)dt} +\frac{f(n)}{2}+\mathcal{O}(f'(n))$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, summation, asymptotics

Someone told me that the following formula holds for $f$ differentiable and decreasing, with $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{f(x)}=0$.

> $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{f(k)} = \int_{n}^{\infty}{f(t)dt} +\frac{f(n)}{2}+\mathcal{O}(f'(n))$$

But I managed to prove only if the function is convex, with the help of the formula

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\int_{0}^{1}{h\left[ f'(x+ht)-f'(x) \right]dt}$$

Which give us integrating it

$$\int_{0}^{1}{f(x+\theta)d\theta}=f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{2}+\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{\theta\left[ f'(x+\theta t)-f'(x) \right]dt}d\theta}$$

And then

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{f(x+\theta)d\theta}
&=\frac{f(x+1)+f(x)}{2}\\&\qquad+\int_{0}^{1}{\left[\left(\int_{0}^{1}{\theta(f'(x+\theta t)-f'(x))dt}\right) -\frac{(f'(x+\theta)-f'(x))}{2}\right]d\theta}\\
&=\frac{f(x+1)+f(x)}{2}+\int_{0}^{1}{\left[\left(\int_{0}^{1}{\theta f'(x+\theta t)dt}\right)-\frac{f'(x+\theta)}{2}\right]d\theta}
\end{align}$$

If we assume that the function is convex, then the term inside the integral is positive, because $f'(x+\theta t)\geq f'(x+\theta)$, and also holds that, as $f'(x+\theta t)\leq f'(x)$ and $f'(x+\theta)\geq f'(x+1)$

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}{\left[\left(\int_{0}^{1}{\theta f'(x+\theta t)dt}\right)-\frac{f'(x+\theta)}{2}\right]d\theta}
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}{(f'(x)-f'(x+1))d \theta}\\&=\frac{f'(x)-f'(x+1)}{2}
\end{align}$$

Summing the expression and using these last inequalities, the result follows.

Can someone help me to prove this for only differentiable functions, not necessarily convex?

Comment: Shouldn't the limit of integration in your formula be $0$ to $\color{red}x$ instead of $0$ to $1$.?

Comment: There was a mistyping but I think that this change that you proposed wouldn't make the formula correct.

Comment: Have you tried applying the Euler-McLaurin formula (with $k=1$) to $[n,m]$,  then using the monotonicity property to bound the remainder term, and let $m\to\infty$?

Comment: Actually I was trying to don't use the Euler-Maclaurin formula exactly because this is a weaker version of this formula. And someone told me that it can be proved without Euler-Maclaurin.

Comment: @Terg Not that it matters too much, but if you want to rekindle interest to your question, I can put a bounty on it.

Comment: I really want a solution because now is not clear for me when this formula is true. Taking out the hypothesis about convexity makes it a lot more powerful.

Comment: @Terg Noted. Let's go for that, then.

Comment: That can't be right. For example, you could have $f'(n)=0$ at all integers, and the formula would assert that the integral ($+f(n)/2$) equals the series, but of course there's no reason for this to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: The key idea is that it's easy to arrange for each $f'(n)$ to be $0.$ That implies $O(f'(n))$ is just the zero function for large $n.$ Then you're left with no wiggle room at all and a counterexample can be found.

For $k=0,1,\cdots$ let $g_k:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous with support in $[k,k+1],$ satisfying

$$\tag 1 \int_k^{k+1}g_k = \frac{3}{4^{k+1}}.$$

Set $g = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}g_k.$ Then $g$ is continuous and nonnegative on $\mathbb R,$ with $g(k)=0$ for all $k.$ From $(1)$ we see

$$\tag 2 \int_0^n g = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{3}{4^{k+1}} =1-\frac{1}{4^n}.$$

Now define $f(x) = 1 - \int_0^x g(t)\,dt.$ Because the integral is increasing, $f$ is decreasing. By $(2),$ $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0.$ From the FTC, we see $f'(x) = -g(x)$ everywhere. In particular, $f'(k)=0,k=0,1,\dots.$

By $(2)$ we see $f(n) = 1/4^n$ for all $n.$ Thus for any $n$

$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}f(k) - \int_n^\infty g = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^k} - \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{3}{4^{k+1}}= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{3}f(n).$$

Because $f'(n) = 0$ for all $n,$ we have a counterexample.

Comment: I feel dumb asking, but why is $g(k)$ zero for all $k$? Did you mean $g'(k)$?

Comment: @ClementC.  Each $g_k$ has support in $[k,k+1],$ hence $g_k(k) = g_k(k+1)=0.$ Thus all $g_k$ vanish on the integers.

Comment: Oops, indeed it was dumb of me. I didn't realize it was "continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with support on $[k,k+1]$" and not "(continuous on and with support in) $[k,k+1]$".

Comment: I now see that @ChristianRemling, in a comment, noticed the idea  described in the first paragraph. His comment was posted before my answer, but I hadn't seen his comment before I posted.

Comment: Yes -- the comment was hidden (Math.SE does that, and it makes it hard to spot interesting comments).

Comment: Very nice! As I was kind of blind when proved for $f$ convex, I couldn't realize that it was false. But now reading your answer I saw that the idea for the counterexample was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a proof can go as follows. Let us for the moment use $M$ as upper limit for the series and the integral. We are looking for a bound on the difference between the series and the integral.
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=n}^{M} f(k) - \int_{n}^{M} f(x)\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{1}{2}[f(M) +  f(n)] + \sum_{j=n}^{M-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} [f(j+1)+f(j)] -\int_{j}^{j+1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x \right) \\
&=
\frac{1}{2}[f(M) +  f(n)] + \sum_{j=n}^{M-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} [f(j+1) +f(j)]  -xf(x) \bigg\rvert_{j}^{j+1} + \int_{j}^{j+1}x f'(x)\mathrm{d}x\right) \\
&=
\frac{1}{2}[f(M) +  f(n)] + \sum_{j=n}^{M-1} \left( -(j+\frac{1}{2}) [f(j+1)-f(j)] +\int_{j}^{j+1} xf'(x) \mathrm{d}x\right)   \\
&=
\frac{1}{2}[f(M) +  f(n)] + \sum_{j=n}^{M-1} \left(-(j+\frac{1}{2}) [\int_{j}^{j+1} f'(x)\mathrm{d}x] + \int_{j}^{j+1}xf'(x) \mathrm{d}x \right)   \\
&=
\frac{1}{2}[f(M) +  f(n)] + \sum_{j=n}^{M-1} \left( \int_{j}^{j+1} (x – j - \frac{1}{2}) f'(x) \mathrm{d}x \right)\end{align}$$
where the second line makes use of an identity, exploiting integration by parts, I saw used in a proof of the Euler-MacLaurin formula.

In the limit $M \to \infty$, $f(M) \to 0$.
 Moreover on the interval $ [j, j+1] $ $$\int_{j}^{j+1} [x – j - \frac{1}{2}] f'(x) \mathrm{d}x   \leq C \lvert f'(j) \rvert     $$ as $f$ is decreasing with $C$ a suitably chosen constant, so that 
$$ \sum_{j=n}^{M-1}  \int_{j}^{j+1} (x – j - \frac{1}{2}) f'(x) \mathrm{d}x \leq C´ \vert f´(n) \rvert    $$
 And I wonder if  this is sufficient to prove the provided statement.
I apologise for the poor editing, due to a ridicolosuly small screen, will be checking in due course.

Comment: Made an attempt at fixing the alignments -- let me know if it looks alright.

Comment: @Clement C., thanks, certainly better than mine.

Comment: I don't understand how you maintain such C for $[n, \infty)$ - you choose one such  constant  for each interval - and the last inequality.

Comment: You're assuming $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: So, I think that continously differentiable is not necessary and even with this I can't see how this sum from $n$ to $M-1$ wouldn't become infinity sum of $|f'(N)|$, which don't give us the asymptotic behavior that we want.